# MSTR IIS server is stopping automatically when trying to load web application (http://localhost/MicroStrategy/asp/)

Tags: microstrategy

MSTR IIS server is stopping automatically when trying to load web application (http://localhost/MicroStrategy/asp/)
The following is the log from  DSSErrors

```
   2016-02-29 14:56:05.988-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:1264][THR:6744][Web SDK BridgeBase][Error] [CRegKeyReader::QueryValueInfo] [Win32 Error][Code: 0x8004403c] 0x2: The system cannot find the file specified.
    2016-02-29 14:56:05.990-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:1264][THR:6744][Web SDK BridgeBase][Error] [CRegKeyReader::QueryValueInfo] [Win32 Error][Code: 0x8004403c] 0x2: The system cannot find the file specified.
    2016-02-29 14:56:05.993-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:1264][THR:6744][Web SDK BridgeBase][Error] [CRegKeyReader::QueryValueInfo] [Win32 Error][Code: 0x8004403c] 0x2: The system cannot find the file specified.
    2016-02-29 14:56:06.079-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:1264][THR:6744][Web SDK BridgeBase][Error] [CRegKeyReader::QueryValueInfo] [Win32 Error][Code: 0x8004403c] 0x2: The system cannot find the file specified.
    2016-02-29 14:56:06.081-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:1264][THR:6744][Web SDK BridgeBase][Error] [CRegKeyReader::QueryValueInfo] [Win32 Error][Code: 0x8004403c] 0x2: The system cannot find the file specified.
    2016-02-29 14:56:06.083-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:1264][THR:6744][Web SDK BridgeBase][Error] [CRegKeyReader::QueryValueInfo] [Win32 Error][Code: 0x8004403c] 0x2: The system cannot find the file specified.
    2016-02-29 14:56:06.709-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:1264][THR:6744][Web SDK BridgeBase][Error] [CRegKeyReader::QueryValueInfo] [Win32 Error][Code: 0x8004403c] 0x2: The system cannot find the file specified.
    2016-02-29 14:56:06.711-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:1264][THR:6744][Web SDK BridgeBase][Error] [CRegKeyReader::QueryValueInfo] [Win32 Error][Code: 0x8004403c] 0x2: The system cannot find the file specified.
    2016-02-29 14:56:06.713-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:1264][THR:6744][Web SDK BridgeBase][Error] [CRegKeyReader::QueryValueInfo] [Win32 Error][Code: 0x8004403c] 0x2: The system cannot find the file specified.
    2016-02-29 14:56:13.683-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:3056][THR:3112][Kernel][Error] ConfigManager::GetServerDefSetting(): ServerDef not initialized: Long SettingId=75.
    2016-02-29 14:56:22.742-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:3056][THR:3188][Kernel][Info] <web_license_info><machine_info><address>DELL-17KBKV1-L7</address><os_name>Windows 7</os_name><os_version>6.1</os_version><processor_count source="Native_code">2</processor_count><jre vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc." version="1.6.0_38"/></machine_info></web_license_info>
    2016-02-29 14:58:43.994-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:8788][THR:8620][Kernel][Info] SetEmergencyReserveSize(): New size = 8388608
    2016-02-29 14:58:44.103-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:8788][THR:8620][Client Connection][Error][0x80041A86] The Location of the data source, CastorServer, is not set.
    2016-02-29 14:58:44.118-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:8788][THR:6680][Kernel][Error] ConfigManager::GetServerDefSetting(): ServerDef not initialized: Long SettingId=75.
    2016-02-29 14:58:44.150-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:8788][THR:8620][Kernel][Error] Configuration file C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MicroStrategy\PerfPflCfg.txt does not exist.
    2016-02-29 14:58:44.586-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:8788][THR:8620][Network Classes][Error] MSINetServerI::InitSSLContext() error: Unable to initialize SSL Context. Please check that the certificate paths and/or key password are correct.
    2016-02-29 14:58:44.586-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:8788][THR:8620][Kernel][Error] StartUpManager::InitChannels(): Fail to start SSL server. One or more required certificates and/or keys may be missing.
    2016-02-29 14:58:44.602-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:8788][THR:8620][Kernel][Error] PUManager::InitPUs: get_ProcessingUnits from ICDSSServerDef failed: 0x00000000
    2016-02-29 14:58:45.054-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:8788][THR:8620][Kernel][Info] Total Virtual Memory (MB): 20180.
    2016-02-29 14:58:45.054-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:8788][THR:8620][Kernel][Info] Used Virtual Memory (MB): 3795.
    2016-02-29 14:58:45.070-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:8788][THR:8620][Kernel][Info] Total Virtual Address Space (MB): 8388607.
    2016-02-29 14:58:45.070-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:8788][THR:8620][Kernel][Info] Used Address Space (MB): 449.
    2016-02-29 14:58:45.070-10:00 [HOST:DELL-17KBKV1-L7][PID:8788][THR:8620][Kernel][Info] I-Server Private Byte (MB): 103
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we figured it out…. we didn’t install the Analytics module, so there is no metadata to connect to.

Here are the steps to install Analytics module

```
We have to start the install program again
Pick Modify
Get to the Select Components part
Check “MicroStrategy Analytics Modules” and install those components

After it is installed, 
Start the Configuration Wizard (in MicroStrategy Tools)
Select “Configure Intelligence Server”
Chose “Analytics_Metadata” for the DSN
Default for Authentication
Default for Server Definitions
Select all Available Projects
Default for SSL Configuration
Click Finish
```

The issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a new server definition with the configuration wizard for the MicroStrategy iServer.

[Relevant discussion on the MicroStrategy Community](http://community.microstrategy.com/t5/Environment-Installation/Microstrategy-Intelligence-Administration-Portal-Error/td-p/105581): check the last post for how to run the configuration wizard again.

Comment: Yes after installing MicroStrategy Analytics components I have created a new server definition

Comment: I think this solved the problem, the analytics modules are just some microstrategy projects, you can have a server without metadata and create them with the configuration wizard